# Laravel foreign key is null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Somehow my laravel relations does not work, if I try to save my foreign keys keep being null.

Clients migration

```
Schema::create('clients', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

inquiry migration

```
Schema::create('inquiries', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('client_id')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedInteger('device_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('android_device_token')->default('');
    $table->integer('status')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('device_id')->references('id')->on('devices')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

trying to put the requests and save it like this, but the database keeps showing me null

```
$data = array(
    "device_id" => $request->input('device_id'),
    "client_id" => Client::find($request->input('client_id'))->id,
    "android_device_token" => $inquiry->android_device_token,
    "status" => $request->input('status')
);
$inquiry->fill($data);
$inquiry->save();
```

The Model relations:

Inquiry:

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Client::class);
}
```

Client:

```
protected $table = 'inquiries';
protected $fillable = ['client_id', 'device_id', 'android_device_token', 'status'];

public function inquiry()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Inquiry::class);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the model for `Inquiry`?

Comment: What does your `$inquiry` have?

Comment: @ArigiWiratama ok I added them above

Comment: Are the necessary fields fillable on your `Inquiry` model?

Comment: @fubar yes I added them above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I know the problem the problem in your model and controller.

Here is my code:

**Client.php**

```php
public function inquiries () {
    // if the relation is one to many
    return $this->hasMany(Inquiry::class);

    // if th relation is one to one
    return $this->hasOne(Inquiry::class);
}
```

**Inquiry.php**

```php
public function client () {
    // It should use belongsTo
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
```

And in your controller should be:

**Controller**

```php
$client = Client::find($request->input('client_id'));
$inquiry = new Inquiry;
$data = array(
    "device_id" => $request->input('device_id'),
    "android_device_token" => $inquiry->android_device_token,
    "status" => $request->input('status')
);
$inquiry->fill($data);
$inquiry->client()->associate($client); // set the foreign key
$inquiry->save(); // save the inquiry
```

**Edit:**
If it caused by fill method. I think in your controller you should change it to this:

```php
// Get the client
$client = Client::find($request->input('client_id'));

// Initiate the Inquiry model;
$inquiry = new Inquiry;
$inquiry->device_id = $request->input('device_id');
$inquiry->android_device_token = $inquiry->android_device_token;
$inquiry->status = $request->input('status');
$inquiry->client()->associate($client);
$inquiry->save();
```

Hope it can help you :D

Comment: call to undefined method associate

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, it should use `$inquiry` to associate not `$client`. Look my edit

Comment: Now the client id is missing do I just add this? `"client_id" => Client::find($request->input('client_id'))->id,`

Comment: you don't have to add `"client_id" => Client::find()` again. `associate` method will fill it for you :D

Comment: I don't understand your last question. It will better if you can make new question about that and make it clear :)

Answer (score 0):

The inquiry model should have the belongsTo relationship:

The inquiry model relationship:

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
```

The client model relationship:

```
public function inquiries()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Inquiry::class);
}
```

Also you could use the `save` method on the relationship in order to save the inquiries:

```
$client = Client::find($request->input('client_id'));

$inquiry = new Inquiry();
$inquiry->fill(array(
    "device_id" => $request->input('device_id'),
    "android_device_token" => $inquiry->android_device_token,
    "status" => $request->input('status')
));
$client->inquiries()->save($inquiry);
```